# (iOS 10, Swift 3) Reading `userInfo` dictionary from a CloudKit notification: How do I cast `[AnyHashable : Any]` to `[String : NSObject]`?

Tags: notifications, cloudkit, swift3, ios10

### Background

I'm trying to load the `userInfo` dictionary from `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo:fetchCompletionHandler` in my app delegate.

I then need to cast `userInfo` from `[AnyHashable:Any]` to `[String:NSObject]` so I can use it in  CloudKit's `CKNotification:fromRemoteNotificationDictionary`.

### Question

When I do:

```
let ui = userInfo as! [String : NSObject]
```

I get the error:

```
'[AnyHashable:Any]' is not convertible to '[String:NSObject]'
```

Is there a better way to convert `userInfo` to the appropriate type, or am I on a completely wrong track?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to cast it first to `NSDictionary` and then you can cast it to `[String: NSObject]`.

Try like this:

```
CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo as NSDictionary as! [String: NSObject])
```

Comment: Nope, if I do it I get:
Cast from '[AnyHashable : Any]?' to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails

Comment: @FabrizioBartolomucci Make sure you unwrap your value before casting. You need to cast from `[AnyHashable: Any]` to `NSDictionary`

Comment: `let d1 : [AnyHashable : Any]? = [1:1];

if let d1  = d1 {
   d1 as NSDictionary
}
`

Comment: Nope, The return of CKNotification is completely empty, it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Loebre make sure you let Xcode autocomplete the method didReceiveRemoteNotification  declaration for you, your method it is probably not getting called

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString.localizedStringWithFormat("%@",(notification.userInfo as! [String: AnyObject] as! [String : NSObject])["theKeyValue"]!)
```

This is how I got the string. Feel free to correct it.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested, it is enough to take away all casts and use userInfo as such for Swift 3 to handle the thing correctly.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Please see Leo Dabus accepted answer above.

Comment: Not quite, at least it compiles fine. Conversely that double casting does not compile at least on Swift 3.